# Linking of Native libraries in above react-native 0.60

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Since in the newer versions of react-native(0.60) automatic linking is been introduced, Previously we use **react-native link "Library name"** command for linking the native libraries.
Now the Library will auto link with the project, Now my question is

1. What can we do with the libraries which is not supporting automatic linking or no longer is maintained with latest version of react-native?
2. Pods are necessary to use with ios? If yes, then what can we do if we were not using pods previously and we have linked some libraries with frameworks and added a .xcodeproject file inside a project? So what will the procedure to link these libraries using pods and newer version?
3. How can we know that in auto lining either the library is linked or not (IOS and Android) ?
4. Is there any manual linking still available after 0.60 version ?
5. react-native unlink can unlink the previously added libraries or newly auto linked libraries ? If no, then how can we unlink a library that is been auto linked with the project ?

Answer (score 0):

1. We have to link them with `react-native link LibraryName` or we can manually link them since they are not updated with latest version of react-native.
2. Yes i guess,On newer versions of React Native, linking is automatic. But to complete the linking on iOS, make sure you have Cocoapods installed. Then Go to ios folder and do `pod install`.
3. You can find info about whether autolinking is supported by library on its installation page. For checking You can check respective OS files and cross check them with manual linking files.
4. Yes.
5. Just run command `react-native unlink LibraryName`.

Comment: i don't think "react-native unlink" or link will work when these libraries is start supporting auto linking, I have tried but no luck.

Comment: Yes. react-native unlink or link will work with libraries that haven't been updated to newer version of react-native

Comment: but what about auto linked ones?

Comment: react-native unlink will do nothing on auto linked library.
eg.
I have installed react-native-gesture-handler which supports auto linking 
But running  react-native unlink  react-native-gesture-handler
It gives following output
>info iOS module "react-native-gesture-handler" is not installed
>info Android module "react-native-gesture-handler" is not installed